# How do I register domain names programmatically?

Tags: registration, domain-name

Any domain name registrars out there that support domain name registration using a web service or a similar functionality without them telling you to become a reseller?

I don't register that many domain names and I am not interested in paying reseller fees.

If I can become a reseller without paying upfront fees, that would be fine.

Comment: What is the issue with having your account labeled "reseller" instead of "retail customer"?  Is it the cost associated with pre-filling your balance?

Comment: I haven't seen any registrar which doesn't ask for upfront fees. I don't care about any label.

Comment: I'm looking for something similar. Let us know what you end up going with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[www.opensrs.com](http://www.opensrs.com) charge a one-off $95 setup fee (which converts into $95 credit on the account). That's not quite what you asked for, but it is pretty low. You get access to a well documented, functional API. However you need to pay for domains by making a credit to your account, then buying the domain from there. I don't think there are any limits on how small this initial deposit can be.

Comment: it's opensrs.com now. I looked through their api documentation. looks nice.

Answer (score 2):

Despite the unfortunate name, [NameCheap.com](http://namecheap.com) have been really good.  I've moved all my domains to them and I've found them to be the best registrar I've come used.

They also have an API ([developer.namecheap.com](http://developer.namecheap.com/docs/)), which is free to use - although you have to either have $200 or greater in your account, have spent $200 in the last two years, or have 20 domains in your account.

I've only just started with the API, but it seems pretty good so far.

Answer (score 0):

[Dotster](http://www.dotster.com/resources/partnerships/) Actually has a free reseller program, and they used to have an API that you could use to register domain names. Something to look into anyway, if you want to automatically register domain names.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the APIs for several registrars when I was working on programatically registering domains.  My needs were basic - I just wanted to register a domain name... not change ownerships, forward URLS, check the weather, or all the other bells and whistles.

I ended up using [Moniker.com](http://www.moniker.com) and found their API to be simple and straight forward.  I read their docs and was up and going within an hour.